# NHibernate - why is this collection not initialized / eager fetched?

Tags: nhibernate, eager

Considering this:

```
var pfs = Session.QueryOver<Pegfile>()
                .JoinAlias(pf => pf.Responses, () => responseAlias)
                .List();
```

followed by this

```
Debug.Print(pfs.First().Responses.Count.ToString());
```

Why would that debug statment make NHibernate go back and requery the Response collection, surely it was initialized in the first query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Fetch` to pre-load the collection:

```
var pfs = Session.QueryOver<Pegfile>()
                .JoinAlias(pf => pf.Responses, () => responseAlias)
                .Fetch(pf => pf.Responses).Eager
                .List();
```

`JoinAlias` aliases the collection so that you can reference it in a where clause, etc.

I'm not sure about QueryOver but the LINQ provider also uses several optimizations that would cause the collection to not be loaded, such as issuing a SQL aggregate `COUNT` query when you invoke `Count`.

Answer (score 0):

Gets me every single time, why don't i remember? **The join has to be a Lefty** - grr love and hate NH in equal measures.

```
var pfs = Session.QueryOver<Pegfile>()
                .Left.JoinAlias(pf => pf.Responses, () => responseAlias)
                .List();
```